# Convert Date to milliseconds and milliseconds to Date

Tags: salesforce-id, datetime, date

I am getting date into JSON as below :

date=1382166999

It seems that date has been returned in milliseconds format.

Can anyone please suggest the way to convert it into normal date format and vice versa ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is known as a "Unix Timestamp" (number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). In Apex Code, you can use `DateTime.newInstance(unixTimestamp)` to return a `DateTime` that contains the formatted date/time value. In JavaScript, use `new Date(unitTimestamp)` to get the same result. To convert back, in Apex Code, use `myDate.getTime()`, and in JavaScript,  use the same function: `myDate.getTime()`.

Comment: I have used it as
`DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(1667277663000);
system.debug(dt);`

but it is giving an error...Illegal integer

Comment: @PARAGTALUKA That's because the number is too large. Make it a long first (suffix with an `l`): `DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(1667277663000l); system.debug(dt);`