# Converting external datetime or timestamp formats using existing methods?

Tags: apex, datetime

I'm making an API callout that returns a date/time in the following format:

```
"Thu May 8 1:21 PM EDT"
```

as well as a timestamp in the following format (millis since unix epoch):

```
"1399569719024"
```

Since these are both fairly common date formats, I'm wondering if Salesforce provides functions to convert this data into values that can be stored in a datetime field, or if I'll have to write some code to convert it? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like I was searching for the wrong terms earlier: searching for unix epoch conversion revealed this link:

[Convert Date to milliseconds and milliseconds to Date](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18958/convert-date-to-milliseconds-and-milliseconds-to-date)

As well as this:

http://www.codetalks.in/2013/08/salesforce-apex-unix-time-stamp-datetime.html

---

EDIT: Oh, also, here's the documentation of the method that works directly with Unix millisecond timestamps

datetime.newInstance(Long)

Constructs a Datetime and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm